# Use tryCatch() but don't overwrite object when error/warning encountered

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch

I want to iteratively fit a `lmer()` model within a `for` loop and store the results. When I encounter an error, I don't want the `merMod` object (the output from the `lmer()` model) to overwrite the `merMod` object from the previous iteration. Example:

```
# install.packages(c("lme4", "dplyr", "ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)
library("lme4")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")

predList <- list()
j <- 1
for(i in 2:9){

  tr <- sleepstudy %>% filter(Days < i)
  pr <- sleepstudy %>% filter(Days == i)

  fm <- tryCatch({lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)},
                 warning = function(w) {#Code to move along to `predict` without overwriting `fm`},
                 error = function(e) {#Code to move along to `predict` without overwriting `fm`})

  #predict the Reaction
  pr$prRe <- predict(fm, pr)

  predList[[j]] <- pr

  j = j + 1
}

pred <- bind_rows(predList) %>% arrange(Subject, Days)
ggplot(data=pred, aes(Reaction, prRe)) + geom_point()
```

This code actually runs no problem. However, let's say when `i=4`, I get a error from `lmer()`. When that happens, I DON'T want to replace `fm` with the error message. Instead, I just want to leave `fm` as it was (the model output from when `i=3`) and move along to the `predict` statement that comes after the `lmer()`. How can I do that?

A special case might be when the very first iteration fails. Let's not worry about that. Assume the first iteration of the loop always successfully fits the `lmer()` model.

One solution might be doing something like:

```
# install.packages(c("lme4", "dplyr", "ggplot2"), dependencies = TRUE)
library("lme4")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")

predList <- list()
j <- 1
for(i in 2:9){

  tr <- sleepstudy %>% filter(Days < i)
  pr <- sleepstudy %>% filter(Days == i)

  fm <- tryCatch({lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)},
                 warning = function(w) {message(w)},
                 error = function(e) {message(e)})

  #If model did not fail, predict as usual and store fm in fm0. If model did fail, use fm0 from previous iteration for prediction
  if(is.null(fm)){
  pr$prRe <- predict(fm0, pr)
  } else
    {fm0 <- fm
     pr$prRe <- predict(fm, pr)
    }

  predList[[j]] <- pr

  j = j + 1
}
```

But that's a little verbose. Is there anything simple I can put within the `tryCatch()` function to simply not overwrite `fm` and move along to the next statement when the model fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a solution, first if you want to not overwrite fm and just go to the next statement:

Initialize fm with some initial model fm0:

```
fm <- fm0
```

Then run your for loop:

```
for ( i in 2:9 ){
    fm <- tryCatch({lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)},
    error = function(e){return(fm)}) #return previous value of fm if error

    # do something else

}
```

However i don't understand why you have two indices `i` and `j`. Notice that `j` starts with a value of 1, and `i` starts with a value of 2. In each iteration both values increment by 1 because of your last line `j = j + 1` so in the next iteration `j` is 2, and `i`is 3 and so on. So your code is the same if you do

```
for (j in 1:8){
   i <- j+1
   #your code here
}
```

and that looks better imho.

Comment: Thanks! Very simple solution!

PS. The reason I have both `i` and `j` is that in my actual analysis, I am iterating over `Week`. Data starts at `Week = 1` and ends at `Week = 567`. However, there are only 450 unique values of `Week` in my data. So, along the way from 1,...,567 over 100 values are missing. I could create a separate variable within the data: `j=1,...,450` but I figured the `i` and `j` indices was just as easy. Thanks!

Comment: ok glad to help. Remember to vote and accept answer if it helped :)